# for loop output in c when maximum value is neative one and assigned value is positive one

Tags: c, for-loop

why output is blank and why loop will run

```
for(i=1;i<=-10;i++)
    printf("*");
```

if i=-1 or i= -10 doesn't matter its run once why

Comment: The printf will not be executed when i is 1, or -1. But once if it is -10.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the condition of the loop is not true even before the first iteration?

Comment: Why do you think the loop is run once if the output is blank. Assuming `i` is a signed type, e.g. `int`, the loop should run 0 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop will iterate as long as `i` is less than or equal to `-10`. As long as `i` is larger than `-10` that condition will never be true and the loop will not iterate, not even once.

If `i == -10` to begin with, the loop will iterate once. Then you do `i++` which increases the value of `i?` to `-9` and the condition becomes false, and the loop won't iterate again.

Note that the above is only true iff `i` is a *signed* integer.

If `i` is an unsigned integer things becomes very different. Then the `-10` will be converted to an unsigned value, and that value will become very large, and the loop will iterate a lot.

Comment: thank you very much sir

Comment: one more question i cant under stand the logic of sp<=(2*y-3) but with this logic program work accurately               [https://bbb-letuscsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/01/chap-3ef-making-alphabet-patterns.html?showComment=1551355852600#c2406906305724625674]

Comment: main()
{
int y,sp,t;
char a,x;
printf("Enter reference alphabet (in capital):");
scanf("%c",&a);
t=a;
for (y=1;y<=(t-64);y++)
{
for (x=65;x<=a;x++)
printf("%c",x);
for (sp=1;sp<=(2*y-3);sp=sp+1)
printf(" ");
if (x==(t+1))
x--;
{
for (x=x-1;x>=65;x--)
printf("%c",x);
}
printf("\n");
a--;
}
getch();
}

Comment: If the `-10` is converted to an unsigned value, it will be a 2's complement value even on those platforms where signed integers are not 2's complement.